# underscore.js templating, iterating over "this"

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

How do I iterate over "this" (or the data object that is passed to the template) using underscore.js templating? For example, if I pass a data object like this into a template:

```
obj = {name: "ben", description: "funny looking"}

var template = _.template("<ul> <% _.each(this, function(x, y){ print('<li>'+x+'<li>')}) %> </ul>"); 

var compiled = template(obj);
```

I would expect "this" in my iterator to loop over the data object (like in Handlebars), but it's not working. Ordinarily I'd directly enter <%= name %> into the template, but in this case, the object keys are being determined dynamically.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can see the compiled version of the template function by looking at `console.log(template.source)`. You'll see that there is no special `this` set up in there, just a `with`.

Comment: Good to know... (By the way, you've helped me with at least three answers. I'm both jealous of your skills _and_ your place of residence!)

Comment: Niether was easy to come by but worth the effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy solution:

```
var compiled = template({data:obj});
```

And then just iterate over "data"